How many edges and vertices for a simple planar graph $G$ with triangular faces, s.t. the faces of $G^∗$ are quadrilaterals?
Context: Given that $G$ is a simple planar graph, where each face of $G$ is a triangle, and each face of $G^∗$ is a quadrilateral, how many edges and how many vertices does $G$ have?
My attempt: I think this question can be solved using Euler's formula, $v−e+f=2$, but I'm not entirely sure how to use that to solve the problem. I proved that $e=2v$ if $G$ and $G^*$ would be isomorphic, wich cannot be. I thought about the relationship between $f$ and $v$. However, I am unsure whether the same relation applies for the inner triangles as for those that are external and no longer enclosed by other triangles. I would appreciate any hints or solutions for this problem:)
Thank you in advance!

Welcome on MSE! Denote $v^\star$, $e^\star$ and $f^\star$ the number of vertices, edges and faces of $G^\star$. Write what you know as equations: 1. $G^\star$ is the dual of $G$ (3 equations) 2. Euler's formula for $G$ 3. Euler's formula for $G^\star$ 4. all the faces of $G$ are triangles and 5. all the faces of $G^\star$ are quadrilaterals. You now have 7 (linear) equations on $v,e,f,v^\star,e^\star,f^\star$, you'll quickly see that $v$ can only take one value.

@Kolakoski54 Euler’s formula for $G^*$ is redundant, but I agree with your comment

Of course it is!

Ah ok, the first 5 Equations are trivial, but for 4.) (all the faces of G are triangles) is it : $f= 2e/3$ and 5.) $f^* = e^*/2$?

Exactly! Now, the solution is clear.

Necessary condition: I will denote by $v$, $e$ and $f$ (resp. $v^*$, $e^*$ and $f^*$) the number of vertices, edges and faces of $G$ (resp. $G^*$). Let me translate the conditions on $G$ and $G^*$ into equations of those quantities:

$G$ is a connected planar graph, by Euler's formula: $$v-e+f=2$$
$G^*$ is the dual graph of $G$:
$$f^*=v,\quad v^*=f,\quad e^*=e$$
All the faces of $G$ are triangles:
$$2e=3f$$
All the faces of $G^*$ are quadrilaterals:
$$2e^*=4f^*$$
You obtain the (linear) system $Ax=b$ where
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}1&-1&1&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0&-1\\0&0&1&-1&0&0\\ 0 & 1 &0& 0 & -1 & 0\\0 & 2 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & -4\end{array}\right),\quad x=\left(\begin{array}{c}v\\e\\f\\v^*\\e^*\\f^*\end{array}\right)\text{ and }b=\left(\begin{array}{c}2\\ 0\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{array}\right)$$
One can easily compute $\det(A)=-2$. Notice that all the entries of $b$ are multiples of $\det(A)$, hence the unique solution $x=A^{-1}b$ must be an element of $\mathbb Z^6$. You can check that the unique solution is given by
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}v\\e\\f\\v^*\\e^*\\f^*\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}6\\12\\8\\8\\12\\6\end{array}\right)$$


Sufficient condition: there aren't many $6$-vertices $4$-regular graphs. On the OEIS, the sequences A006820 gives the number of $n$-vertices $4$-regular graphs, and the $6$th entry is $1$: the octahedral graph (with its dual the cubical graph) is the only solution to your problem. We can now state the result:
Proposition: For a planar connected graph $G$, the following statements are equivalent:

$G$ is 4-regular and $G^*$ is 3-regular;
$G$ is the octahedral graph.

Here is a drawing of $G$ and its dual $G^*$:


In general, if you want your (simple) graph to be $m$-regular and its dual to be (simple) $n$-regular (or equivalently, the faces of $G$ are $n$-gones and the faces of $G^*$ are $m$-gones), then you get the system $Ax=b$ where
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}1&-1&1&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0&-1\\0&0&1&-1&0&0\\ 0 & 1 &0& 0 & -1 & 0\\0 & 2 & -n & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & -m\end{array}\right),\quad x=\left(\begin{array}{c}v\\e\\f\\v^*\\e^*\\f^*\end{array}\right)\text{ and }b=\left(\begin{array}{c}2\\ 0\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{array}\right)$$
The determinant of $A$ is $mn-2n-2m$, which is nonzero when $m$ and $n$ are integers, except when $(m,n)\in\{(3,6),(6,3),(4,4)\}$. For all those cases, we can check that there is no solution. When $\det(A)\ne 0$, we get
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}v\\e\\f\\v^*\\e^*\\f^*\end{array}\right)=\frac{2}{2n+2m-mn}\left(\begin{array} \phantom{}2n \\mn\\2m\\2m\\mn\\2n\end{array}\right)$$
Without loss of generality, we can suppose that $m\leqslant n$. $v$, $e$ and $f$ are positive integers if and only if $m=2$ or one of the five following cases:

$m=3$ and $n\in\{3,4,5,6\}$;
$m=4$ and $n=4$;

The $2$-regular connected graphs correspond to cycles, but their dual is not simple, so we can exclude those cases.

For all the other cases:

for $(m,n)=(3,3)$, we obtain the tetrahedral graph (autodual):



for $(m,n)=(3,4)$, we obtain the cubical graph (whose dual is the octahedral graph):



for $(m,n)=(3,5)$, we obtain the dodecahedral graph (whose dual is the icosahedral graph)



for $(m,n)=(3,6)$ and $(m,n)=(4,4)$, there are no solutions.

A more general result would therefore be:
Theorem: For all simple connected planar graph $G$ whose dual $G^*$ is also simple, the following statements are equivalent:

$G$ and $G^*$ are regular.
$G$ is a platonic graph.
$G^*$ is a platonic graph.


Very nice diagrams! I will note one technicality in the $(m,n) = (3,5)$ case: though it is easy to solve the equations and find out the number of vertices, edges, and faces, it is not so easy to prove that the only planar graph with the desired structure is the dodecahedral graph. (It is possible, but tedious - though of course it can be done by brute force if necessary.)

Thank you. Indeed it is not immediate, if you have any elegant way to show it, I'd be glad to add it!

The best I know is Lemma 1.1 in this paper, but it is still not what I'd call elegant.

I am still relatively new to LaTeX, could you tell me how you drew these graphs? Is there a method in LaTeX, or a program to create them?

With the TikZ package (for complex figures, you can easily find WYSISYG TikZ editors online !)
